# 0-1 laws in random graphs: probability $\beta$ is large if $k$ is large

Tags: probability, graph-theory, probability-inequalities

How has the author derived [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9606226.pdf)

on the page 3 in the context of random graphs and 0-1 laws

that
$\beta$ is large if
$$k\geq ((\frac{2}{\alpha})\log n)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ ?

What I did is this:

I've substituted $1$ for $\beta$
in $$\frac{k\cdot \beta}{n}\leq\frac{1}{k^{\alpha \cdot {k\choose 2}}}$$
and I got
$$(\alpha \frac{1}{2}\cdot k \cdot (k-1)+1) \leq \log_k n$$
hence approximately
$$k\leq (\frac{2}{\alpha} \log_k n)^\frac{1}{2}$$

This is good, but the inequality is *reversed* unlike the one on the page 3 which is "$k \geq$" there
which confuses me. Apparently the author considers **both** inequalities as he says there

> the bound for the other direction has the same order of magnitude.

I would like to understand which direction of the inequality is the right one and
how this $\beta$ largeness follows from
$$\frac{k\cdot \beta}{n}\leq\frac{1}{k^{\alpha \cdot {k\choose 2}}}$$

Comment: Maybe it's a mistake? If I understand correctly $\alpha$ and $n$ are both positive, which would mean that as $k$ increases, the given upper bound on the probability increases, which contradicts the claim that a larger $k$ results in a smaller probability.

Comment: @fblundun That's what I think too. But don't you have a typo in your comment too? you write [...]the given upper bound of the probability **increases** but the r.h.s. with increased $k$ **decreases**. It's mind boggling anyway.

Comment: I don't think there's a typo in my comment... I'm saying that as $k$ increases, $(1 - (\frac{1}{k^\alpha})^{k \choose 2})^\frac n k$ (which is the upper bound on the probability in question) increases.

Comment: @fblundun And whence have you taken the assertion in your first comment that larger $k$ results in a smaller probability ?

Comment: I'm not saying that the paper is claiming there's a monotonic relationship between $k$ and the probability, just that the paper is claiming to deduce from the upper bound on the probability that for all sufficiently large $k$, the probability is "small". But I think that as $k \to \infty$, the upper bound $\to 1$, so I don't see how that deduction is possible.

Comment: @fblundun Dear Fblundun Would it be better (would you understand) my original question **if** the inequality were reversed :  $\beta$ is large if
$$k\leq ((\frac{2}{\alpha})\log n)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ ?? Would this statement be correct now ?

Comment: @fblundun Dear Fblundun have you noticed my last additional question ?